# Using Boost Spirit's stream parser with custom grammar

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

### Synopsis

I would like to harness Boost Spirit's [stream parser API](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/parse_api/stream_api.html) to parse an `std::istream` incrementally. However, I could not find a good example of how to use it with an iterator-based grammar. Conceptually, my goal is to parse an infinite stream of objects of type `T`.

### Details

A grammar in Qi with an attribute of type `T` and skipper `S` typically has the form:

```
template <typename Iterator>
struct grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, T(), S>;
```

How do I use such a grammar with the stream-based API? Specifically, my mental model for the stream API is that I can do something along the lines of:

```
// Callback invoked for each successfully parsed instance of T.
void f(T const& x)
{
}


// What iterator type?
grammar<???> parser;
skipper<???> skipper;

T x;

std::ifstream ifs("/path/to/file");
ifs.unsetf(std::ios::skipws)
while (! ifs.eof())
{
    ifs >> phrase_match(parser, skipper, x);
    if (ifs.good() || ifs.eof())
        f(x);
}
```

I am struggling with bringing together traditional grammars requiring iterators. How does that fit together with the stream API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the [Spirit multi-pass iterator](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/support/multi_pass.html). Note, however, that parsing of the stream will *not* be done incrementally unless you go out of your way to make sure your grammar has minimal backtracking.